# How to get day of week from date?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

For one of my fetches I need to check if `DOW(date) IN :listOfDow`:

```java
@Query("SELECT event FROM Event event WHERE DOW(event.date) IN :dows")
List<Events> getEvents(@Param("dows") Collection<DayOfWeek> dows);
```

Obviously, `DOW()` does not exist. So, is there a way to do this in HQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the JPQL function calls like `WHERE function('dayofweek', event.date) IN :dows`, but that is very database-specific.

`dayofweek` is MySQL-specific function returning 1-7 where 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday, where as `weekday` returns 0-6 with 0 being Monday.

If you're using Postgres you can use `function('date_part', 'dow', event.date)` to get it with Sunday starting as 0.

If you're using another database you will have to check it's documentation to find an appropriate function that is also registered by the selected Hibernate Dialect.